# How to make "interaction from event" box in a unity custom editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new at editor scripting and i try my best to integrate tools in my scripts.
And as i learning more about it i wonder, is there a method to recreate the "on click" option
of the UI Button  or is it linked to unity event in some way ?
It's really flexible and you can put everything you want in that box to react to the button click.[The UI Button inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZyq8.png)

i've try looking into the button script but it import a lot of thing and is pretty obscure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.